# Issue reading line and printing everything together in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to write a code that reads line by line and stores it in a variable sdp. This is what I would paste in the console to be read and I want the sdp to appear in that same format.

The idea would be to read every line, and put a end of line character and for every read reallocating extra memory.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
            printf("[Description]: ");
              char *line;
              size_t len = 0;
              ssize_t read = 0;
              char *sdp = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
              while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1 && all_space(line)) {
                sdp = (char*) realloc (sdp,(sizeof(sdp)) +sizeof(line));
                strcat(sdp, line);
                strcat(sdp, "\r\n");

                free(line);
              }
              printf("%s\n",sdp);
              rtcSetRemoteDescription(peer->pc, sdp, "offer");
              free(sdp);
```

This is what I am trying to read and store in the variable sdp

```
    v=0
    o=- 118260718 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=group:BUNDLE 0
    m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=ice-ufrag:r4nc
    a=ice-pwd:USf61+k7dRjSFJFZIlZkNn
    a=ice-options:trickle
    a=mid:0
    a=setup:actpass
    a=dtls-id:1
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 21:C5:F4:72:3C:BA:4F:4A:DD:F1:14:C5:15:A9:57:4E:5B:61:44:CB:9B:7C:FC:2A:D3:0D:90:99:47:53:A9:57
    a=sctp-port:5000
    a=max-message-size:262144


But i keeping getting a problem, sdp doesnot store all the value and the result after printing is strange. 
can someone help me
2020-05-11 21:24:28.287 DEBUG [15263] [rtc::InitLogger@34] Logger initialized
Peer created
Reached this point

***************************************************************************************
* 0: Exit / 1: Enter remote description / 2: Enter remote candidate / 3: Send message / 4: Print Connection Info *
[Command]: v=0
o=- 118260718 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:r4nc
a=ice-pwd:USf61+k7dRjSFJFZIlZkNn
a=ice-options:trickle
a=mid:0
a=setup:actpass
a=dtls-id:1
a=fingerprint:sha-256 21:C5:F4:72:3C:BA:4F:4A:DD:F1:14:C5:15:A9:57:4E:5B:61:44:CB:9B:7C:FC:2A:D3:0D:90:99:47:53:A9:57
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:262144user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ o=- 118260718 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
118260718: command not found
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ s=-
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ t=0 0
0: command not found
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ a=group:BUNDLE 0
0: command not found
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
9: command not found
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
IP4: command not found
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ a=ice-ufrag:r4nc
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ a=ice-pwd:USf61+k7dRjSFJFZIlZkNn
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ a=ice-options:trickle
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ a=mid:0
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ a=setup:actpass
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ a=dtls-id:1
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ a=fingerprint:sha-256 21:C5:F4:72:3C:BA:4F:4A:DD:F1:14:C5:15:A9:57:4E:5B:61:44:CB:9B:7C:FC:2A:D3:0D:90:99:47:53:A9:57
21:C5:F4:72:3C:BA:4F:4A:DD:F1:14:C5:15:A9:57:4E:5B:61:44:CB:9B:7C:FC:2A:D3:0D:90:99:47:53:A9:57: command not found
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ a=sctp-port:5000
user@user-MXC6300:~/Desktop/WEBRTC/build$ a=max-message-size:262144
```

Comment: `sizeof(sdp)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of the block that the pointer points to.

Comment: The same with `sizeof(line)`. That should be `strlen(line)+1`.

Comment: `strcat(sdp, line);` causes undefined behavior on the first iteration, because the contents of `sdp` are not initialized.

Comment: Still having the same issur

Comment: Try to initialize also the "line" pointer with NULL. And reset that pointer after free(line) also with NULL (and reset len = 0 also there). Then replace (sizeof(sdp)) +sizeof(line) by (strlen(sdp) + len + 2).

Comment: Thank you very much